# Couchbase Full Text search with combination of dynamic fields and N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Consider following documents and consider that is created Full-text index over following documents:

```
{
    email : "A",
    "data" : {
        "dynamic_property" : "ANY_TYPE",
         "dynamic_property2" : {
            "property" : "searchableValue"
         },
         "field" : "VALUE"
    }
},
{
    email : "B",
    "data" : {
        "other_dynamic_prop" : "test-searchableValue-2",
    }
},
{   
    email : "A",
    "data" : {
        "thirdDynamicProp" : {
                "childProp" : "this should be searchableValue!"
         }
    }
}
```

The goal: Create N1QL query which will match all the documents with have associated given `email` address **AND** the `data` property contains given substring.

Basically following:

```
SELECT * FROM `bucket` WHERE `email` = 'A' AND `data` LIKE '%searchableValue%';
```

The expected result is the first and second document because matching criteria. But the query does not work because data is **not a text type** but is **object type**. If the `data` property would be like:

```
{"data" : "this should be searchableValue!" }
```

The query would return expected result.

The question is:
**How to create such a N1QL query which would return expected result?**

---

I know that Couchbase is not able to do compare substring in the text, but using Full-text index it should be possible since Couchbase 4.5+

Comment: All versions of Couchbase since 4.0 can answer your query. As @prasad said, Couchbase 4.6 can answer your query using a TOKENS index and a slightly modified query, using ANY ... SATISFIES ... to match the index.

Comment: I am using Couchbase 4.5. How would you do it in version 4.5 without using Full-text index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the specific queries based on the answer from @prasad.

Using Couchbase 4.5:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_email ON `bucket`( email );

SELECT *
FROM `bucket`
WHERE
    `email` = 'A'
    AND ANY t WITHIN `data` SATISFIES t LIKE '%searchableValue%' END;
```

Using Couchbase 4.6:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_email ON `bucket`( email );

CREATE INDEX idx_tokens ON `bucket`( DISTINCT ARRAY t FOR t IN TOKENS( `data` ) END );

SELECT *
FROM `bucket`
WHERE
    `email` = 'A'
    AND ANY t IN TOKENS( `data` ) SATISFIES t = 'searchableValue' END;
```

Comment: `Using Couchbase 4.5:`  You did not define any index on the `data` field. How it can be search able?  How about searching for substrings? It just forces me create an index. *"No primary index on keyspace.."*

Comment: Did you create the index on email?

Comment: Yes, I did create the index.

Comment: And are you getting the correct results? You have to use the exact index and the exact query I posted.

Comment: Yes, I did. I am using just Couchbase 4.5, so I've created an index just for an email column. I don't have the index on `data` object.

Comment: Correct results? If so, you can mark the answers and close the issue.

Comment: No I am not getting correct result. Actually query does not work.

Comment: Ok. Let's fix the query on the Couchbase forums and then post the final answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase4.6 and 5.0 have more/better options (explained below). In couchbase4.5, you can use Array Indexing to solve this:

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html

https://www.couchbase.com/blog/2016/october/n1ql-functionality-enhancements-in-couchbase-server-4.5.1

For instance, using the `travel-sample` sample bucket, following array index, and query would do the kind of substring search you want.

```
create index tmp_geo on `travel-sample`(DISTINCT ARRAY x FOR x IN object_values(geo) END) where type = "airport";

select meta().id, geo from `travel-sample` where type = "airport" 
and ANY x IN object_values(geo) SATISFIES to_string(x) LIKE "12%" END;
```

N1QL introduced a function TOKENS() in 4.6, which can help you create functional index on tokenized sub-objects (instead of array index in the above example):

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/string-functions.html

https://dzone.com/articles/more-than-like-efficient-json-search-with-couchbas

And,  Couchbase 5.0 developer build (https://blog.couchbase.com/2017/january/introducing-developer-builds) has N1QL function CURL(), which allows you to access any HTTP/REST endpoint as part of the N1QL query (hence, can access the FTS endpoint). See following blogs for more details & examples:
  - https://blog.couchbase.com/2017/january/developer-release--curl-n1ql
  - https://dzone.com/articles/curl-comes-to-n1ql-querying-external-json-data

Btw, can you clarify if you want partial tokens or only full tokens in the query?

-Prasad

Comment: I need to be able using Couchbase 4.5. And I not only need to be able search in arrays but in dynamic objects.